# Custom Navigation bypass SharePoint Group and use AD Groups

Tags: permissions, 2016, navigation

I have a custom **SharePoint 2016** on prem Navigation with links only certain people can see.  Currently I am using a SP Group and manually updating it when there is a new hire with their AD account.

What I would like to do is bypass the SP Group and use AD groups so I don't have to manually update anymore.  Hope this makes sense.

Below is my code to read from the SP Group.

```
   var allowedGroups = ["IT"];
   var isInAllowedGroup = false;

   var userid= _spPageContextInfo.userId;
   var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/_api/web/CurrentUser/Groups?$select=Id,Title';

//alert(requestUri);
   var requestHeaders = { "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" };
   $.ajax({
     url : requestUri,
     contentType : "application/json;odata=verbose",
     headers : requestHeaders,
     success : onSuccess,
     error : onError
   });

  function onSuccess(data, request){
 var s='';
  for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++)
 {
 s +=data.d.results[i].Title+'\n';



  var groupName = data.d.results[i].Title;
   if (allowedGroups.indexOf(groupName) > -1)
   {
    isInAllowedGroup = true;
   }
 }

if(isInAllowedGroup){
 $("#IT").css('display', 'block');
 }

     (s);
 }
   function onError(error) {
     ("error");
   }

 });
```

thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to modify your process, and not your code.  Add the AD group to the SharePoint group, then add users to the AD group.